# Checkmark on badge page not vertically aligned

Tags: bug, design, badges, user-interface

The checkmark besides the badge on the Badges page is not vertically aligned to the badge.

It appears that this can be fixed by changing `vertical-align: top;` **to `vertical-align: middle;`** in the following line in `secondary.css`:

```
.badges-page .single-badge-table .single-badge-wrapper .single-badge-badge {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Current CSS (`vertical-align: top;`):**

> [image]

**Corrected CSS (`vertical-align: middle;`):**

> [image]

---

FWIW the checkmark displays correctly on the list of badges page ([`/help/badges`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges)):

> [image]

Comment: Odd that I never noticed it until now even though it’s been like this for at least 5 years ;)

Comment: But once you see it, you can't forget it. ;)